# Is §3.3.7/4 from N4567 redundant?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

According to N4567, 3.3.7 paragraph 4 says,

> The potential scope of a declaration that extends to or past the end of a class definition also extends to the regions defined by its member definitions, **even if the members are defined lexically outside the class**...

However, I don't see a need for making it clear because such a member definition must be in the scope of that declaration regardless of its lexical positioning. In other words, it seems there is no case where such a member definition dwells outside the scope of the declaration. See the following example:

```
int always_visible=10;

class some {
    int foo(void);
};

int some::foo(void) {
    // no ambiguity occurs because its member definition
    // is always in the scope of always_visible.
    return always_visible;
}
```

I don't think it's possible for its member definition to precede the declaration of always_visible, in which case the wording above might be useful. Then, why is that clarification needed?

Comment: The member definition could be in a different file? Maybe [like this](http://pastebin.com/BWqSkVVc)?

Comment: `#include members.c`

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't think that's possible because the maximum declarative region is a translation unit. In fact, that gives me an error.

Comment: @Pétur That inclusion, if successful, ultimately results in the precedence of the declaration relative to the member definition.

Comment: Personally, I don't know of a case (offhand) where the potential scope of a declaration of a member extends past the end of a class definition. Perhaps when the class is unnamed and the ember-name is an enumerator (?). In the other cases, the potential scope of a member only extends till the end of the class definition, since afterwards you need to qualify the member name with the class name such as `classname::membername`. As such, the clarification is necessary, I would say.

Comment: Also consider `namespace A { int i = 0; struct B { void f(); }; } void A::B::f() { int x = i; /* visible! */ }`. The `i` is visible, even if the definition of `A::B::f` isn't nested within `A`. Although, these rules feels kind-of duplicative with the "shall be declared in..." rules of 3.4.1 (unqualified name lookup), which defines the potential scope aswell. The very definition of potential scope is based on the success of unqualified name lookup, more or less (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Forgive me for taking so long to reply your comments. First of all, the example you just gave me clearly suggests that there is a case where a member definition resides in outer scope of the declaration in question. That means my hypothesis was wrong and my question is nicely answered by you!

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb However, I really want to ask you about what you meant by your first comment. The point of my question was not about the potential scope of a member—it's more of whether the potential scope of the declaration in question reaches out to the outer member definition. Can you elaborate on how that's related to my question?

Comment: @Il-seobBae Let me intrude my thoughts here. I suppose, he implied these words in 3.3.7\1: "rules describe the scope of names declared **in classes**". But the words "past the end" in 3.3.7\1.4, 1.5 imply, I think, not names declared in classes, but names declared in a some enclosing declarative region (namespace A in his example) of a class. So potential scopes of such names indeed may extend past the end of the class definition and they extend to the end of their declarative region (namespace A). So...

Comment: @KerrekSB In addition, they don't belong to the same type, I suppose.

Comment: @EugeneZavidovsky I don't know what you're talking about. That's exactly all I said before. The intention of my comments is to ask him about why he did ever mention the potential scope of **a member**.

Answer (score 0):

The main situation where the potential scope of a declaration that extends *to* the end of a class definition also extends to its member definitions is when the declaration in question is a member of that class:

```
class C {
    int x;
    int f();
};

int C::f() {
    return x;
}
```

`x` is in scope at the point of its use in the definition of `C::f`, but it wouldn't be in scope after the closing brace of `C` otherwise.

What about the "or past the end" part? Well, it can easily occur with nested classes:

```
class Outer {
    static int x;
    class Inner {
        int f();
    };
};

int Outer::Inner::f() {
    return x;
}
```

Here, because `x`'s potential scope extends *past* the end of `Inner`'s definition, all the way to the end of `Outer`'s definition, `x` is also in scope within the definition of a member of `Inner`.